# unsuccessful VPN connection

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, connection-issues, vpn

I'm unable to connect my phone to VPN, it always say "unsuccessful". I deleted the profile and created it again but it didn't help. What is wrong with it?

Comment: are you using a 3rd party VPN or the built-in one?

Comment: @forums: The latter.

Comment: I'm going to assume you are using Android's VPN client. Have you tried to connect other droids to the VPN and had success?

Comment: @forums: I used the connection before successfully(in my smartphone), the issue has appeared recently.

Comment: what I mean is can you still access your VPN thru other means? it might be the VPN is down. If that is not the case, did you recently installed a program before you can't connect?

Comment: @forums: Yes, I can connect to it from my laptop. And no, I haven't installed any apps on it recently.

Answer (score 0):

The only surefire fix I can suggest is factory reset. But I know it should be your last resort so maybe it can also be fixed by resetting the settings to defaults, without losing data. This method sometimes work with broken wifi, issues with force close, some lagging issue and some others.

**First**, if you have [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&hl=en) or other similar apps, backup your system data (Settings, ApplicationSettings, Settings Storage) because you will be wiping it clean.
 **2nd**, Go to Settings -> Applications -> All, and scroll down until you find `Settings`. Select it, now you will see some info, scroll down until so see `Clear data`. Note that clearing data will set your Wifi, Wallpaper, Sound, Network, but not your password and google login, to defaults.
Now after clearing Settings, go back to Applications -> All, and check if you also have `VPNservice`, and `Network Provider` there, clear its data too to be sure.

Try to login your VPN now, it should probably work. If not, use whatever last resort you have. But remember to backup first :P

Answer (score -1):

you might try out 3rd party softwares like hot spot shield [Hot spot shield](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hotspotshield.android.vpn) [Flash VPN](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flash.VPN_Free)